# How to get Area of Polygon in acres using GeoTools API

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I have extracted coordinates from Shapefile using GeoTools API.
I am using getAreaFunction to get the area of the polygon - but getting result in something like 7.695432394893684E-8.
How to convert this result into acres?

Comment: Perhaps your shapefile is not projected. You need to check the projection. After projecting, you can easily calculate the area in acres.